taro packaging error failed to recognize the protocol starting with ext
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "ext://industry/index" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "ext:" URIs.
